# Codeigniter user_agent

Tags: codeigniter, user-agent

This is my first time developing a responsive website, and I attempted using the CodeIgniter user_agent class.

I notice that there's

```
is_mobile()
```

and

```
is_browser()
```

However, the picture I have in mind is for the website on a tablet to look pretty similar to the browser, and only the mobile site to load a different `view` file altogether.

However, is_mobile() includes both tablets and mobile phones, and it's not what I'm hoping for. Is there an alternative to this?

Reason: I am using jQuery mobile, and I load a completely different layout for the mobile phone, and I don't want this view to appear on tablets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

You can extend the library and create a method to check for tablet:

```
class MY_User_agent extends CI_User_agent {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function is_tablet()
    {
        //logic to check for tablet
    }
}

// usage
$this->load->library('user_agent');
$this->user_agent->is_tablet();
```

Or you could override the existing `is_mobile()` method in the library to have the functionality you want:

```
class MY_User_agent extends CI_User_agent {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function is_mobile()
    {
        // you can copy the original method here and modify it to your needs
    }
}

// usage
$this->load->library('user_agent');
$this->user_agent->is_mobile();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

---

### Example

application/libraries/MY_User_agent.php:

```
class MY_User_agent extends CI_User_agent {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function is_ipad()
    {
        return (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad');
            // can add other checks for other tablets
    }
}
```

controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('user_agent');

    ($this->agent->is_ipad() === TRUE) ? $is_ipad = "Yes" : $is_ipad = "No";

    echo "Using ipad: $is_ipad";

}
```

Comment: `Agent` in the class names should not be capitalized.

Comment: @Cryode noted and fixed... Thanks.

Comment: could u point me in the right direction for solution 2? (extending `is_mobile` to only mobile phones

Comment: Actually it's probably better to create a separate method.. See the updated answer with Example. If you want to check for more than just iPad, you can add user agents to look for in MY_User_agent. If you want to check for all tablets, check out this library: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect