# Exclude Ipad and tablets from is_mobile

Tags: php, android, ios, ipad, codeigniter

I'm using this function so the page loads different on mobile phones:

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('ua', '_mobile');
}
else {
    $this->session->set_userdata('ua', '');
}
```

This is on my_controller.php of codeigniter.

The problem is that I want it to work only on **mobile phones** and not on Ipads or other tablets.

Any ideas how can I modify it?

Comment: You can reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089200/codeigniter-user-agent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use core php code as below:

```
$iPad     = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$Tablets  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Tablet");
```

Then you can apply your logic.

**Note**: Check the case of text `iPad` and `Tablet` from  `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

Found a link from CI forum: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/207100/#964021

Please check.

Comment: I'm curious...are `iPad` and `Tablet` the only types of tablets? It doesn't get any more specific than that?

Comment: @user2537383. I don't know. this may be helpful for codek to fix his issue. Frankly to say,  I'm not aware of Tablets :-)

Comment: This worked for me: 
                                  ` $iPad = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPad");
                                    $Tablets = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Tablet");
                                    $dropContent = wp_is_mobile() && !$iPad && !$Tablets ? 'content for mobile' : 'content for tablets and desktop' ;
`